# Python in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS gives error /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 version `GLIBC_2.25' not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, glibc

I get this problem when I try to run Python 3.6 on my Ubuntu:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found
```

what can be the cause of that?

Comment: How do you invoke Python? How did you install this version of Python?

Comment: I installed that using Pycharm, that I thing uses virtualenv. 
This Python version is on the server that I can access with 2 machines, one is a Kubuntu (I dont remember the version) and one is Ubuntu 16.04LTS. Python works when I run it from the Kubuntu machine but not when I try on the Ubuntu.

Comment: I invoke python by using an alias that I defined in .bashrc that points to bin/python3.
When I invoke python2.7 instead (also installed with virtualenv)  everything works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You somehow installed python3.6 that was compiled/linked against GLIBC-2.25 (or later). This binary can not run on any machine which has older GLIBC.

The solution is to either build or install python3.6 that is targeted to *your* machine.